# Convert this long console.log to a loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have to convert temperature in javascript

So I made the first for loop to console all the fahrenheit temps, I then created a function to convert fToC. It all works and I get my results but is there a way to loop the long console log to convert fToC?

```js
for (let fahrenheit = 20; fahrenheit <= 120; fahrenheit = fahrenheit + 5) {
  console.log(fahrenheit);
}

function ftoC(fahrenheit) {
  let celcius = (fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8;
  return celcius;
}
console.log(ftoC(20));
console.log(ftoC(25));
console.log(ftoC(30));
console.log(ftoC(35));
console.log(ftoC(40));
console.log(ftoC(45));
console.log(ftoC(50));
console.log(ftoC(55));
console.log(ftoC(60));
console.log(ftoC(65));
console.log(ftoC(70));
console.log(ftoC(75));
console.log(ftoC(80));
console.log(ftoC(85));
console.log(ftoC(90));
console.log(ftoC(95));
console.log(ftoC(100));
console.log(ftoC(105));
console.log(ftoC(110));
console.log(ftoC(115));
console.log(ftoC(120));
```

Comment: under `console.log(fahrenheit);`, add `console.log(ftoC(fahrenheit));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's incrementing by a fixed number, there's a very simple loop you could use. Here's a for:

```
const min = 20;
const max = 120;
for(let i = min; i <= max; i+=5)
{
    console.log(ftoC(i));
}
```

Or a while:

```
let i = 20;
const max = 120;
while(i <= max)
{
    console.log(ftoC(i));
    i += 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more modern version

```js
const ftoC = fahrenheit => ((fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8).toFixed(2);
const pad = (num,spaces) => (""+num).padStart(spaces," ");
const res =  [];
[...Array(141).keys()] // create an array from 0-141
  .slice(20)           // chop the first 20 
  .forEach((_,i) => { if (i%5 === 0) res.push(`${pad(i,3)}C: ${pad(ftoC(i),6)}F`) // save if i modulo 5 is 0
  });
  document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = res.join('<br/>')
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do thank you. If I chose to document.write(i,ftoc(i) it would not display the same way as it does in console log. I am guessing I would have to put. a break in like so (i, ftoC(1) <br>)

Comment: nope just tried to display it using document write to no avail at least where it looked legible

Comment: See new version